# System.Windows.Clipboard usable in WPF apps, but not Console apps

Tags: c#, visual-studio, clipboard

I tried to write a very small app for manipulating the system clipboard. The class used is `System.Windows.Clipboard`.

When I write it with VS template of Console app, it does not work, reporting: "The name 'DataFormats' does not exist in the current context".

(code in Program.cs)

```
using System;
using System.Windows;

namespace clipboard_console
{
    public class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            string textData = "XYZ";
            DataObject data = new DataObject(DataFormats.UnicodeText, (Object)textData, true);
            Clipboard.SetDataObject(data, true);
        }
    }
}
```

To make it work, I need to use the VS template of WPF app, but running the app would popup a blank window.

(code in MainWindow.xaml.cs)

```
using System;
using System.Windows;

namespace clipboard_wpf
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            string textData = "XYZ";           
            DataObject data = new DataObject(DataFormats.UnicodeText, (Object)textData, true);
            Clipboard.SetDataObject(data, true);
        }
    }
}
```

How can I get an app that quiely changes the clipboard content only? Thank you!

---

Reply to Answer no.1

Hi @digital_jedi Thanks for your solution!

My default project file is like this:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

I follow your recommendations to change it to:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net7.0-windows</TargetFramework>
    <UseWPF>true</UseWPF>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Now the references seem to be ok. But running it lead to the error message:
[image]

Comment: Put the [STAThread] attribute on Main().  Edit the project file to target, say, net6.0-windows and add `<UseWPF>True</UseWPF>`

Comment: @HansPassant  Adding the [STAThread] attribute does make it work. Thank you! Another question: is it possible to prevent the console window from showing up?

Comment: Change the OutputType to WinExe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clipboard is available in `System.Windows` namespace (PresentationCore.dll included in WPF apps) and also `System.Windows.Forms` namespace (System.Windows.Forms.dll included in WinForms apps). You can reference either from your console project by doing the following (example for net 6):

PresentationCore.dll:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">  
  <PropertyGroup>  
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>  
    <TargetFramework>net6.0-windows</TargetFramework>  
    <UseWPF>true</UseWPF>
  </PropertyGroup>  
</Project>
```

System.Windows.Forms.dll:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">  
  <PropertyGroup>  
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>  
    <TargetFramework>net6.0-windows</TargetFramework>  
    <UseWindowsForms>true</UseWindowsForms>  
  </PropertyGroup>  
</Project>
```

Note the `-windows` suffix on the `TargetFramework`, and the usage of `<UseWPF>true</UseWPF>` or `<UseWindowsForms>true</UseWindowsForms>`. You could also reference both like so:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">  
  <PropertyGroup>  
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>  
    <TargetFramework>net6.0-windows</TargetFramework> 
    <UseWPF>true</UseWPF>
    <UseWindowsForms>true</UseWindowsForms>  
  </PropertyGroup>  
</Project>
```

**EDIT:**

Given the issues with WPF regarding hiding the window and trying to shutdown the exe afterwards, I recommend using the `System.Windows.Forms` clipboard instead of WPF.

Setup reference like so:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">  
  <PropertyGroup>  
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>  
    <TargetFramework>net6.0-windows</TargetFramework>  
    <UseWindowsForms>true</UseWindowsForms>  
  </PropertyGroup>  
</Project>
```

Main.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ClipboardApp
{
    public class Program
    {
        [STAThread]
        public static void Main()
        {
            string textData = "XYZ";
            DataObject data = new DataObject(DataFormats.UnicodeText, textData);
            Clipboard.SetDataObject(data, true);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your further answer! As suggested by @HansPassant, changing the output to WinExe works perfectly. And "<UseWPF>true</UseWPF>" is ok.

Answer (score -1):

A very simple way, use `This.Hide();`

You can then hide your WPF blank window.

```
using System.Windows;

namespace WpfApp1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            string textData = "XYZ";
            DataObject data = new DataObject(DataFormats.UnicodeText, textData, true);
            Clipboard.SetDataObject(data, true);
            this.Hide();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It works. Thank you for the solution! Sorry for another question: is this the best (or lightest) way for writing such kind of very small tools?

Comment: An issue with the wpf method is: after running the compiled .exe, the clipboard is changed successfully, but the exe file persists in the memory. How can I make it automatically exit after modifying the clipboard?

Comment: @kaspa I recommend switching to System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard to avoid these issues. See my edited post above.